# How can I interpret the following typedef statement

Tags: c, type-conversion, typedef

## How can I interpret following typedef statement.

I already have some knowledge through type convertions. They are used to reinterpret the bytes behind a variable as another type. Example:

```
unsigned char* byte = (unsigned char*) (some signed char);
```

But now I see following statement:

```
typedef void (*uv_read_cb)(uv_stream_t* stream, ssize_t nread, uv_buf_t buf);
```

https://github.com/bodokaiser/libuv/blob/master/include/uv.h#L314

What totally confuses me are:

- there is no name of the typedef
- how can we do a type conversion on some arguments???

Has somebody an answer on these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typedef does have a name... `uv_read_cb` which is a pointer to a function that accepts a `uv_stream_t*`, a `ssize_t`and a `uv_buf_t` argument and returns `void`.

This allows you to add things like a pointer to a function in a structure, passing function pointers to functions, etc., while allowing you to define what type of function can be assigned to the variable or passed...

```
typedef void (*uv_read_cb)(uv_stream_t* stream, ssize_t nread, uv_buf_t buf);

struct myVTable
{
    uv_read_cb  uv_read_callback;
};

void myVFunction(  uv_stream_t* stream, uv_read_db callback )
{
     ssize_t length = 100;
     uv_buf_t buf;
     myVTable table;

     table.uv_read_callback = callback;

     table.uv_read_callback( stream, length, buf );

     // or you could alternatively use 'callback( stream, length, buf );'
}
```

Comment: I believe that `table.uv_read_callback( steam, lenght, buf );` instead of `callback( steam, length, buf );`, at the end of your example, would be more appropriate to explain how pointers to functions are helpful.

Comment: Fair enough- Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer to a function that gets `uv_stream_t*`, `ssize_t` and `uv_buf_t`, and returns void.
`uv_read_cb` is also the type, and you can use it to define other functions with the same signature.
For example:

```
uv_read_cb my_func;
```

Comment: So it used to check if a function takes the defined parameters without being to strict on the implementation itself (which would be the case when using a direct function definition)? Am I one right way? What would be a little more expressive example?

Answer (score 1):

This statement defines `uv_read_cb` as a pointer to a function that returns void.

Comment: Almost: s/as a pointer to/as an alias for the *type* pointer to/